# How can I pass a variable to a query inside a shell script?

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus

```
while IFS=# read -r process_id source destination type
do
        echo "Process id: $process_id"
        echo "Source: $source"
        echo "Destination: $destination"
        case "$type" in
                2)
                echo "Type is outbound: $type"
                        contact=$(sqlplus -s ${SQLPLUS_INFO} <<EOF
                        SET PAGESIZE 0
                        SELECT email FROM table WHERE partner = '${destination}';
                        exit
                        EOF
                        )
                echo
                echo ${contact}
                echo
                ;;
```

Based in the code above, how can I pass the value from $destination to the query? The example above is not working, even these other ones:

```
SELECT email FROM table WHERE partner = '"${destination}"';
SELECT email FROM table WHERE partner = '$destination';
```

Comment: take out the `contact=$(` and `)` just to see if that is source of the problem. I would expect this to work as is, but the command-substitition (`$( ...)`) might be a problem. Good luck.

Comment: As a separate idea, add `export destination` before calling the `contact=$(....)`. Good luck.

Comment: contact=sqlplus -s ${SQLPLUS_INFO} <<EOF
                        SET PAGESIZE 0
                        SELECT email FROM table WHERE partner = '${destination}';     
                        exit
                        EOF

Did not work as well, it returned: 

 line 73: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Just using the ( ) did not work as well, returning:

syntax error near unexpected token `<<'
.
.

PS: The export also did not work

@shellter, @Emmanuel

Comment: no, I meant take the chars `contact=$(` AND `)` (only).Add an `exit` statement right after EOF, to see if the `sqlplus <<EOS ... EOS` stuff is working, without worrying about the assigning to the variable `contact`. As usual, JonathanL is giving you excellent advice. I would add that you're getting into complicated territory, you'll have to slow down a bit and take the time to understand what each bit of syntax that is added to your script is doing, both in a basic sense as well as what you hope it is doing in your particular case. Good luck.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens when you run the script with `bash -x`?  I ask because the here-document notation expects to find the end marker at the start of a line.  When I run this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

    contact=$(cat - <<EOF
    input from here document
    second line
    EOF
    )

echo "$contact"
```

I get errors like:

```
eof.sh: line 3: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
eof.sh: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

If the lines start with tabs, you can use a dash before the end-of-file marker to indicate that leading tabs should be ignored.

```
#!/bin/bash

        contact=$(cat - <<-EOF
        input from here document
        second line
        EOF
        )

echo "$contact"
```

This outputs:

```
input from here document
second line
```

Replace those tabs with blanks and you are back into the syntax errors.  Although I've couched this in terms of `bash`, I believe you run into the same issues with Korn and Bourne shells too.

So, my suspicion is that your problem is related to the formatting of the here-document in your code, but you should have been seeing some sort of error, so I'm a bit puzzled.  You should be getting the substitutions you wanted made:

```
#!/bin/bash

description="The Description"

        contact=$(cat - <<-EOF
        input from here document
        second line with '$description' embedded.
        EOF
        )

echo "$contact"
```

This yields:

```
input from here document
second line with 'The Description' embedded.
```

Using `bash -x` can be helpful to trace the execution of a command.

All of this is only coincidentally related to Oracle and SQL*Plus.

Comment: I guess I found the problem with bash -x

+ echo 'Destination: x                       '
Destination: x
+ case "$type" in
+ echo 'Type is outbound: 2'
Type is outbound: 2
++ sqlplus -s user/pass@EDDB
+ contact='
no rows selected'
+ echo

+ echo no rows selected
no rows selected
+ echo

The query is returning lot of spaces:

+ echo 'Destination: x                       ' <<<<< blank spaces

I set the:

set linesize 1000
set trimspool on
set pagesize 0
set colsep #

but looks like it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to remove the single quotes around your variable: they prevent your variable to be interpreted (contrary to double quotes).

That should be:

```
SELECT email FROM table WHERE partner = ${destination};
```

Comment: Now it returned:

SELECT email FROM table WHERE partner = X; script.sh result.csv SELECT.sql ERROR at line 1: ORA-00904: "X": invalid identifier

Did not work, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: SQL requires a text value to be surrounded by single quotes.